# Upgrading 10g database to 11g database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, upgrade

Is doing a full data export (expdp) from an Oracle 10g (10.2.0.1.0) database and then doing an import of that dump file (impdp) into an 11.2.0.2 database a valid and acceptable upgrade path from 10g to 11g?

Answer (score 1):

Sure-- there is even a chapter in the Upgrade Guide on [using DataPump to move the data from the old database to the new database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e23633/expimp.htm).